# Best way to return huge dataset where data can be analyzed asynchronously

Tags: database, performance

This is a general question on handling huge sets of data returned for analysis.

I am using python, but don't think the programming language or db server type is important for this.

I currently have a huge set of data that is returned which takes about 20mins.  I can use the data as soon as it arrives for analysis by using multiple threads/processes.  The problem is waiting for the data.

1. I belive I could use paging for the data, but this still requires me to wait for the data which is really the problem.
2. I could break the query for the data into many separate calls so I can have 10 calls going at once all grabbing a different parts of the table via a where clause.
3. Is there a better way?  Again, I need to get the data from the table(s) to the application as fast as possible.

Also - when I query a database for data, what is it that really determines the speed that the data returns?

1. Let's say the db server and my app are on the same machine.  Is there a limiting speed due to a single connection/request to the db server?
2. If I am on an intranet - will the db connection use up as much bandwith as possible when sending?

do you know any into tutorials on performance of a database query (no where clause - just return all rows)?  Will the query use the max connection speed and bandwidth?

Thanks - yes I am a new to db considerations.

Comment: A bigger part of the performance implications depends on the query you are using. Please add the specific query you want to use.

Comment: "...The problem is waiting for the data..." - This points to a query that is internally materialized rather than being pipelined. If the query were pipelined you would start receiving the first rows right away, not after 10 mins.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long.  Looks like I did a bad job of explaining the issue.  Let's not worry about which db I'm going to use - just theoretical for now.  I have one table that I have over 3 million records.  I want to load them into a map after some analysis and processing.  I want to load the data as fast as possible.  What is the best approach?  If I make one connection - it takes about 10mins.  If I make a bunch of connections and use a where clause to break up the returned data - it will take less time.  Is this the best way?  Only way?  Is there a better way?

Comment: Pipelining the data does not get it to the app any faster (It does chunk it up so I can process bits at a time).  I want to get all the data down to app asap.